# How to use Windows hosts file to access my website url from another laptop or system

Tags: windows, jsp, netbeans, xampp, localhost

I have done a project using Netbeans 8.2, Apache Tomcat 8, MySQL database (XAMPP). My OS is Windows 10. It is successfully executed on my laptop.

Now I am trying to access my project url (http://dms.zf.com:8084/newFieldsAdded/login.jsp) from another laptop but failed. So I searched the web and I got [solution like this](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-modify-your-hosts-file-in-windows-10-and-why-you-might-want-to). I added

```
10.226.43.47    dms.zf.com
```

My laptop IP address and name into hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) file. Then I tried with this url (http://dms.zf.com:8084/newFieldsAdded/login.jsp) on my browser, it is successful. but it is not accessible from other laptop.

Before doing changes in hosts file url was http://localhost:8084/newFieldsAdded/login.jsp and after adding `10.226.43.47    dms.zf.com` in hosts file URL is http://dms.zf.com:8084/newFieldsAdded/login.jsp.

Comment: You need to reach the site from your internal network or from internet?

Comment: A hosts file has only its effect on the system you modified it. If you want to make your website public, you should look into port forwarding and get a DNS.

Comment: @alessiosavi internal network only

Comment: @CoderCharmander how to do this with DNS. Can you please help me with DNS?

Comment: @alessiosavi which procedure should I follow to access my website url from other PC's??

Comment: please help....